# labeling connections in a decision tree

Tags: tikz-pgf, labels, tikz-trees

I an customizing a ready script for building decision trees using the `TikZ` package, but am unable to label the connections between nodes in any way? Are there tools for labeling connections in decision trees? Also, how do I ensure that my label is always above the connection? I've included the code and the output. I drew the connection labels on the output to show what I'm trying to achieve.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf, tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[sibling distance=15em,
every node/.style = {shape=rectangle, rounded corners,
    draw, align=center,
    top color=white, bottom color=gray!20}]]
\node {no slopes}
child { node {subj slope} 
    child { node {subj \& item slopes} 
        child { node {\textbf{max RE}} }
        child { node {\textbf{subj slope}} }}
    child { node {item slope} 
        child { node {subj \& item slopes} 
            child { node {\textbf{max RE}} } 
            child { node {\textbf{item slope}} } } 
        child { node {\textbf{no slopes}} } }};
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: tree]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `forest` key `edge label` can be used to add labels for connections

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
for tree={l sep+=.8cm,s sep+=.5cm,shape=rectangle, rounded corners,
    draw, align=center,
    top color=white, bottom color=gray!20}
[no slopes
  [subject slope
     [subj \& item slopes,for children={font=\bfseries},edge label={node[midway,left]{$\checkmark$}} 
       [max RE]
       [subj slope]     
     ]
     [max RE,font=\bfseries,edge label={node[midway,right]{$\times$}}  
       [subj \& item slopes,for children={font=\bfseries}
         [max RE]
         [item slope]       
       ]
       [no slopes]
     ]
   ]  
]    
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: tree]

Comment: You've changed the structure of the tree. I realise the problem is that it is not actually a tree, but it still seems potentially undesirable.